How to get the direction of the realtime traffic data from TomTom?
I've constructed the Protobuf schema using the template from the documentation and successfully extract data. The list of the values representing the available tags are as follows:

road_type
traffic_level
traffic_road_coverage
left_hand_traffic
road_closure
road_category
road_subcategory

Does TomTom provide the direction of the traffic_level?  For example, if the traffic level is 0.4, how to tell whether this is for, say, heading East or West?  The Eastbound traffic could be very heavy whereas the Westbound traffic could be at the free-flow speed.
traffic_road_coverage indicates "if the traffic is assigned to the whole road (one way road), or only to one side (two-way road)", but doesn't seem to provide any directional value.

Not 100% sure, but probably you can only get the direction based on the feature's geometry.

@szogoon Could you elaborate on what that means?

Each flow is represented by a linestring. If it goes from the bottom of the tile, to the top, then it is heading north.

That actually makes sense.  I'm currently trying out map-matching services that use things like Viterbi algorithm to guess what road a series of coordinates could represent probabilistically, also taking into account the flow of the coordinates as you mentioned.  Do you know of known methods for achieving this?
